# Adding object to hash/array using a object's property as a key

Tags: javascript

```
var generated_Obj= {
              id: 'unqiue',
              ....
              some other properties
            }

            var hash = {};
```

I would be grateful to know how to add `generated_Obj` to hash using `generated_Obj.id` as a key.

If a solution with `push()` method is possible I would like to learn about it either, ofcourse if there's approach that is efficent it's better

10x for your kind help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add things to an object (what you called a hash) using the `[]` operator:

```
hash[generatedObject.id] = generatedObject;
```

Comment: how would you add an object with the same name?

Comment: @Trip: I don't really understand your question. Do you want to have two elements with the same key?